# python max function with mixed strings and numbers

Tags: python, max

Could someone explain to me why the following code :

```
li = [u'ansible-1.1.tar.gz', u'ansible-1.2.1.tar.gz', u'ansible-1.2.2.tar.gz', u'ansible-1.2.3.tar.gz',
      u'ansible-1.2.tar.gz', u'ansible-1.3.0.tar.gz', u'ansible-1.3.1.tar.gz', u'ansible-1.3.2.tar.gz',
      u'ansible-1.3.3.tar.gz', u'ansible-1.3.4.tar.gz', u'ansible-1.4.1.tar.gz', u'ansible-1.4.2.tar.gz',
      u'ansible-1.4.3.tar.gz', u'ansible-1.4.4.tar.gz', u'ansible-1.4.tar.gz']

print(max(li))
```

returns :

```
ansible-1.4.tar.gz
```

Thank you

PS: It returns 1.4.4 when there are only numbers (1.4, 1.4.4, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they are compared lexicographically:

```
>>> ord('t'), ord('4')
(116, 52)

>>> 't' > '4'
True

>>> 'ansible-1.4.tar.gz' > 'ansible-1.4.4.tar.gz'
True
```

To get `ansible-1.4.4.tar.gz` as result, you need to pass key function.

For example:

```
>>> li = [u'ansible-1.1.tar.gz', u'ansible-1.2.1.tar.gz', u'ansible-1.2.2.tar.gz', u'ansible-1.2.3.tar.gz',
...       u'ansible-1.2.tar.gz', u'ansible-1.3.0.tar.gz', u'ansible-1.3.1.tar.gz', u'ansible-1.3.2.tar.gz',
...       u'ansible-1.3.3.tar.gz', u'ansible-1.3.4.tar.gz', u'ansible-1.4.1.tar.gz', u'ansible-1.4.2.tar.gz',
...       u'ansible-1.4.3.tar.gz', u'ansible-1.4.4.tar.gz', u'ansible-1.4.tar.gz']
>>>
>>> import re
>>> def get_version(fn):
...     return list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', fn)))
...
>>> get_version(u'ansible-1.4.4.tar.gz')
[1, 4, 4]
>>> max(li, key=get_version)
'ansible-1.4.4.tar.gz'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another good solution,

Python has its own module called **pkg_resources** which has method to **parse_version**

```
>>> from pkg_resources import parse_version
>>> max(li, key=parse_version)
u'ansible-1.4.4.tar.gz'
>>>
```